# Which is grammatically correct: „Der Saal war voll Menschen“ or „Der Saal war voll von Menschen“?

Tags: preposition, usage

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> Der Saal war voll Menschen.
>   Der Saal war voll **von** Menschen.